# The property 'IsDataSource' was not found in type 'ViewModelLocator

Tags: mvvm, expression-blend

I have the following code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.View.ViewAlarmLog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"  
 xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary  >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <mvvm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
  </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

the problem is dat i always get an error:
The property 'IsDataSource' was not found in type 'ViewModelLocator'. "

What could be the problem here ?

Redgards
Dieter

Answer (score 22):

I think the IsDataSource attribute is specific to Expression Blend. Other editors, like Visual Studio, won't be able to understand it.

You can fix this problem by instructing the editor to ignore this attribute.

Try adding the following attributes to the UserControl element:

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"    
mc:Ignorable="d"
```